# React + Redux + Router теряется state при смене страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

Reduser.js

```
const defaultState = {
    isAuth: false,
}

const AUTH = "AUTH";

export const userReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        ...
    }
}

export const authUserAction = (payload) => ({type: AUTH, payload});
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  const isAuth = useReduser(state => state.isAuth);

  useEffect(() => {
      ... // какое-то условие
      dispatch(authUserAction(true))
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Routes>
                {isAuth && <Route path="/authPage" element={<AuthPage />} />}}
                <Route path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
                
                // Редирект (*)
                <Route 
                    path="*"
                    element={<Navigate to="/" replace/>}
                />
            </Routes>
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

В моем проекте есть страницы, которые можно посещать только если пользователь авторизован, и если не авторизованный пользователь попытается посетить такую страницу, сработает редирект на главную страницу *(*)*.

При загрузке страницы, в `useEffect`, происходит проверка jwt токена и смена Redux стейта.

Если перейти на другую страницу, то переменная `isAuth` 'потеряет' свой стейт и придется ещё раз проверять авторизован ли пользователь. но так как `useEffect` срабатывает после рендера, то успеет сработать редирект на главную. В этом и заключается ошибка.

Можно ли как-либо 'связать' redux и react-router

Comment: Я пробовал использовать react-router-redux, но статьи видимо устарели и в их решениях нужен hashHistory. в моем пакете react-router такого объекта нет (использую 6 версию)

Comment: "Если перейти на другую страницу, то переменная isAuth 'потеряет' свой стейт" - зачем? Смысл каждый раз проверять логин? Ключ должен ставиться только при логине/регистрации 1 раз и 1 раз должен пропадать, если разлогинился юзер и всё

Comment: @EzioMercer Но isAuth лежит в глобальном стейте и если я залогинюсь и перейду на другую страницу, то этот стейт пропадает. Как сделать чтобы он не пропадал? И useEffect по идее должен вызываться только один раз ведь список зависимостей пустой

Comment: У вас есть `Redux` - значит есть возможность там хранить значение, а его достать проще всего через `useReduce()`, ну а при экшенах устанавливаем туда значение

Comment: @EzioMercer для большей ясности я обновил код. Повторюсь, всё что лежит в глобал стейте теряется при перезагрузке, или смене страницы. Я спрашиваю о решении, которое поможет сохранить стейт, когда пользователь переходит по ссылке

Comment: Не хотите использовать `localStorage` или что-то на подобие этого?